# LD_LIBRARY_PATH works but ldconfig does not

Tags: qt, shared-library

Qt until 5.13 has weird bug for me, so I tried to change library version of Qt to most recent version (5.15). I installed Qt 5.15 libraries to `/home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib`, and set up `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/Qt.5.15.0.conf` accordingly. Here is the result of `ldd usr/bin/konsole`:

```
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5X11Extras.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Svg.so.5)
/usr/bin/konsole: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5TextToSpeech.so.5)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc6592000)
    libkdeinit5_konsole.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_konsole.so (0x00007f01a80dc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f01a7eea000)
    libkonsoleprivate.so.19 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkonsoleprivate.so.19 (0x00007f01a7d79000)
...
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f01a6e95000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f01a6561000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f01a6016000)
...
```

It seems like programs(in this case, konsole) seems to still load older library from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Strange thing is that only libQt5Core has this problem, while other Qt librarys are properly loaded.

If I do something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/" /usr/bin/konsole` It then works properly. But Ubuntu 20.04 does not like setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH from .profile, and I am looking for workarounds. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug/defect of ldconfig addressed here:https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26663

In short, ldconfig completely ignores library priority when OS ABI tag is given. OS ABI tag of Default system qt library was 3.17.0, while 5.15.0 library was 2.6.28. This puts Default system qt library always before 5.15.0 library in ldconfig hierarchy. You can confirm this behavior with `ldconfig -p`.

The workaround I choose is to patch OS ABI tag of 5.15.0 library. In this case, I used the commands:

```
echo -en "\x04\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x47\x4e\x55\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" > patch.txt
objcopy --update-section .note.ABI-tag=patch.txt /home/myaccount/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/libQt5Core.so.5.15.0 patched.so
```

And then replace `libQt5Core.so.5.15.0` with `patched.so`. I don't think this is a recommendable solution, but it does work. Make sure to create backup.